# Terminal corruption and garbage issues with tmux when emojis are used

Tags: terminal, tmux, weechat

I'm having issues whenever an emoji is displayed inside one of my tmux windows. Everything becomes garbled and mixed, but the inputs still work. I have to clean the screen and detach/attach to fix it. It happens no matter what font or ssh client I use (tried putty and xshell). Example:
[image]